# Sum of Colored Special Characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, colors, special-characters

I am trying to count the Modules + Hours per column.

The Symbols used are special Characters + Colored.

In the Excel cell it shows "u u"

- A Red and Yellow "u u" means 2h
- A Green and Yellow "u u" means 1h
- A Blue and Yellow "u u" means 0.5h

Is it possible to sum the characters?

```vb
Public Function SumColorRed(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In pRange1
    If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
        SumColor = SumColor + 2
    End If
Next
End Function
```

The List (can't show the names) there are about 50 of these lists
[image: The List (Can't show the names) there are about 50 of these lists]

Comment: Can you show how this files look like?

Comment: In your position I'd be trying to influence whoever produced the sheet you provide to change the way in which they represent things to a more manageable form.

Comment: Thank you 
However i tried for 1 year already. This wont change fast.

Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is simple: The cell text is really `u u`, just formatted with Font WinDings which will diplay a **◆**

If you use `rng.Font.Color` to read or set the color, this means the color is valid for the whole cell. If you want to get (or set) the color (or other properties like Bold or Italic) for single characters, you can use the `Characters`-Property. You need to specify the start and the length as parameters, eg `rng.Characters(3, 1)` to the 3rd character of a cell.

The following code looks to the first and third character of a cell and checks the colors. I am not 100% sure that my color definitions are exact the colors that are used in your sheet, maybe you have to adjust the constant definitions.

```
Function getColorTime(cell As Range) As Date
    
    Const redCharColor = &HFF&
    Const yellowCharColor = &HC0FF&
    Const greenCharColor = &H50B000
    Const blueCharColor = &HC07000

    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long
    c1 = cell.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color
    c2 = cell.Characters(3, 1).Font.Color
    ' Debug.Print c1, c2
    If c1 = redCharColor And c2 = yellowCharColor Then
        getTime = TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
    ElseIf c1 = yellowCharColor And c2 = greenCharColor Then
        getTime = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
    ElseIf c1 = blueCharColor And c2 = greenCharColor Then
        getTime = TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my two cents:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=CountColor(A1:A4)
```

Refering to UDF:

```
Function CountColor(rng As Range) As Double

Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In rng
    Select Case cl.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color & "|" & cl.Characters(3, 1).Font.Color
        Case "255|49407"
            CountColor = CountColor + 2
        Case "12874308|4697456"
            CountColor = CountColor + 1
        Case "49407|4697456"
            CountColor = CountColor + 0.5
        Case Else
            CountColor = CountColor
    End Select
Next

End Function
```

Obviously, you'd want to find out the color-codes for your "aces".

Comment: Sir, Super Amazing ! Definitely needs to bookmarked.